# JavaScript/Jquery Como puedo vaciar un select dinamico y dejarle un value por defecto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```js
    //Despliego las categorias, dependiendo del valor seleccionado en el slc Seccion
    $('#slcSecciones').bind('change', function(e) {
        var valorSeleccionado = $('#slcSecciones option:selected').val();
        if (valorSeleccionado != "undefined") {
            DesplegarCatXSecc(valorSeleccionado);
            $("#slcEstilos").empty().append('<option value="0">Seleccione una opcion...</option>');

        }
    });
    
    //ACA SERIA CUANDO CAMBIO EL VALOR DE MI PRIMER SELECT(que todos dependen de el) 
    //lo que quiero es que cuando cambie un valor del primer select(Seccion), en el select de estilos me apareza Seleccione una opcion...
```

```html
<div>
                <b>Secci&oacute;n:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcSecciones">
           <option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div>
                <b>Categor&iacute;a:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcCategorias">
                        <option value="0 "selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div>
                <b>Estilos:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcEstilos">
                        <option value="0 " selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            
            
            <!-- ESTOS SON MIS SELECT DINAMICOS
                QUE POR DEFECTO CUANDO ME INICIA LA PAGINA ME APARECE SELECCIONE UNA OPCION 
                YO LO QUE QUIERO ES QUE AL HACER EL EMPTY, ME VUELVA A APARECER SELECCIONE UNA OPCION...-->
```

Buen dia!
Tengo un select dinamico, que traigo los datos de mi base de datos(mediante ajax), mi problema es que:

Tengo mi primer select, que se llama Seccion, que los demas dependen de el, yo quiero que al tenerlos todos cargados, al cambiar mi select seccion, los demas pierdan sus valores y le muestre al usuario "Seleccione una opcion..."

Lo que yo utilizo es un :

```
$("#miSelect").empty();
```

Esto funciona bien, el problema es que cuando me vacia, me deja cargado en el select el valor que tenia antes, por ej tenia cargado "nombre", lo vacio -queda vacio- pero me muestra "nombre" -que en realidad ya no esta mas-

Intente con

```
$("#miSelect").empty().append('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');
```

pero no funciona

Comment: puedes mostrar el código HTML para ver como lo hiciste

Comment: Lo que tienes te debería funcionar. Si puedes subir el **HTML** como te comenta el compañero @JohnySalazar podríamos ver que te está ocurriendo.

Comment: ahi lo subi! en realidad no es a partir de un boton que haga el cambio, es a partir de un 'change' de mi select principal

Answer (score 3):

Saludos te propongo lo siguiente:

```js
//detecto el evento click de boton Reinicar Select
$("#btnReset").click(function(){
  //remover todas las opciones excepto la primera
 $("#frutas").find('option').not(':first').remove();
  $("#animales").find('option').not(':first').remove();
  //establecer seleccionado la primera opcion
 $("#frutas").val($("#frutas option:first").val());
  $("#animales").val($("#frutas option:first").val());
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Seleccione una fruta: <br>
<select name="frutas" id="frutas">
 <option value="" disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" selected>Manzana</option>
  <option value="2">Pera</option>
  <option value="3">Uva</option>
</select>
<br>Seleccione un animal: <br>
<select name="animales" id="animales">
 <option value="" disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1" selected>Perro</option>
  <option value="2">Gato</option>
  <option value="3">Leon</option>
</select><br><br>
<button id="btnReset" type="button">Reinicar Select</button>
```

**Explicación**

Lo que hace básicamente es detectar el evento click del boton "**btnReset**" por su **ID** al detectar el evento click lo primero que hago es eliminar o remover todas las opciones excepto la primera que sera "Seleccione" con:

```
$("#mi_id").find('option').not(':first').remove();
```

Luego de esto establezco por defecto seleccionado la primera opción con:

```
$("#mi_id").val($("#mi_id option:first").val());
```

con esto obtendrás lo que necesitas espero te sirva..!!

Comment: No entendi bien, yo por defecto cuando inicio la pagina me aparecen todos los select vacios y me muestra "Seleccione una opcion... " como muestra el html..

Y lo que me sucede es que cuando los cargo todos, cuando los quiero vaciar  con .empty() .. quiero que me vuelva a aprecer como antes! que me muestre Seleccione opcion..

Y lo que sucede es que me aparece el valor que tenia antes, y el seleccione opcion me aparece cuando le doy click al select! Yo quiero que aparezca de primera, a la vista del usuario

Comment: @tato8vio lo que te indico en mi respuesta es como limpiar tus select y dejar por defecto un value tal como comentas en tu pregunta

Comment: No me funciono, de todas formas edite la pregunta porque no es a partir de un boton, es a partir de mi primer select que va en cascada, entiendo a donde quieres llegar pero no me ha solucionado el problema..

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una ejemplo de como puede funcionar un `select` dependiente con `HTML5` y `jQuery` con la característica que buscas... *Al seleccionar el valor de cada `select` cambie los demás `select`*

Se que no es exactamente tu código, pero necesitaba crear un ejemplo verificable para que compruebes que funciona. Con este código como base podrás adaptarlo a tu necesidad.

```js
$('#seccion').on('change',function(){
  var seccionID = $('#seccion').val();  
  if(seccionID == 1){
    $('#categoria').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una sección</option><option value="1">Categoría 1</option><option value="2">Categoría 2</option>');
    $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option>');
  }else if(seccionID == 2){
    $('#categoria').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una sección</option><option value="3">Categoría 3</option><option value="4">Categoría 4</option>');
    $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option>');
  }else{
    $('#categoria').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una sección</option>');
    $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option>');
  }
  
  $('#categoria').on('change',function(){
    var categoriaID = $('#categoria').val();
    if(categoriaID == 1){
      $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option><option value="1">Estilos 1</option><option value="2">Estilos 2</option>');
    }else if(categoriaID == 2){
      $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option><option value="3">Estilos 3</option><option value="4">Estilos 4</option>');
    }else if(categoriaID == 3){
      $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option><option value="5">Estilos 5</option><option value="6">Estilos 6</option>');
    }else if(categoriaID == 4){
      $('#estilos').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option><option value="7">Estilos 7</option><option value="8">Estilos 8</option>');
    }else{
      $('#categoria').html('<option value="">Seleccione primero una sección</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <b>Sección</b>
  <select name="seccion" id="seccion">
      <option value="">Seleccione una sección</option>
      <option value="1">Sección 1</option>
      <option value="2">Sección 2</option>
  </select>
<div>
</div>
  <b>Categoría</b>
  <select name="categoria" id="categoria">
      <option value="">Seleccione primero una sección</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Estilos</b>
  <select name="estilos" id="estilos">
      <option value="">Seleccione primero una categoría</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esto a ver si te sirve utiliza la funcion prepend() para agregar el option

qudaria asi :

```
$('#slcSecciones').bind('change', function(e) {
    var valorSeleccionado = $('#slcSecciones option:selected').val();
    if (valorSeleccionado != "undefined") {
        DesplegarCatXSecc(valorSeleccionado);
        $("#slcEstilos").empty();
        $("#slcEstilos").prepend('<option selected="true" value="0">Seleccione una opcion...</option>');

    }
});
```

tambien le agrege el atributo selected pare ver si quita la opción seleccionada antes